# Android Wifi P2P : failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 1080): isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: android, sockets, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I'm using [this](https://github.com/life0fun/wifi-direct-chat) to build a wifi P2P application and when I try to connect two devices, I get the below error.

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.49.1 (port 1080): isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

The app worked for couple of times initially, but now fails to connect all the time.

I have added a `Thread.sleep(2000);` before it makes a connection just in case if it is a problem of race condition. But still fails.

I have tried using different port numbers, restarted phone but nothing works.

What could be the reason?

Also tried connecting to another network, but in vain.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

One more question is that the IP address from `WifiP2pInfo` always returns the same address i.e. `192.168.49.1` all the time. Is this behavior expected.

Answer (score 0):

The github project seems quite old (no updates in the last 4 years). You can implement your own p2p connection using the [Android framework APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html), which would only take a day.
For your second question, yes, it is normal that it uses the same address every time if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

This IP is hardcoded in the android source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/net/wifi/+/84befe36af491f26ae46243017a1aca4dd5b24d5/service/java/com/android/server/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pServiceImpl.java

You can find this constants by  "SERVER_ADDRESS"